# Why it is not recommended to index relationships in a graph database

Tags: neo4j, graph-theory

In the book [Neo4j in Action](https://neo4j.com/books/neo4j-in-action-book/) by Aleksa Vukotic and Nicki Watt, the authors say:

> In our experience, it is less common for relationship indexes to be good solutions. We are not saying that relationship indexing is poor practice, but if you find yourself adding lots of relationship indexes, it is worth asking why.

It sounds that the authors do not recommend to index relationship in a graph database but no explanation is given thereafter. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Often 'in our experience...' is a substitute for 'We haven't the foggiest idea why, but...'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, it's important to understand the role of indexes in Neo4j, in that indexes are used to find starting points in the graph, after which relationship traversal and filtering are used to perform the remainder of the pattern matching and to complete the query.

The advice therefore is about the same as: "we do not recommend using relationships as starting points in the graph", and we find that true more often than not.

Usually when you need to do index lookups, you have certain "things" in mind as your starting places, and important things in graphs are typically represented by nodes. If we're asking "what employees are connected to this particular company" we're interested in starting quickly by finding that particular company and expanding out, not in finding all :EMPLOYED_BY relationships in the graph and filtering by the connected company, which would take far more time.

Often we find that those who encounter this restriction, and need this kind of fast lookup of relationships anyway, may need to rethink their model. Often when there is a need to lookup relationships as starting places in the graph, it is an indication that the thing represented by a relationship is important enough that it really should be a node in the graph (with its own relationships to the previously connected nodes), so this becomes a "modeling smell" that drives refactoring changes to the model. Often this kind of change feels more natural after, and affords more capability for the thing as a node that wasn't available when it was being modeled as a relationship (for example, the ability to apply multiple labels to it, or to connect it via relationships to more nodes than just the original two).

All that said, there will be cases where a relationship really does just need to be a relationship (either for business reasons, or because it truly is most practical modeling-wise for it to be kept as a relationship), and using those relationships as starting points in the graph make sense.

With the [fulltext schema indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/index/#schema-index-fulltext-search) introduced in Neo4j 3.5, we added the capability to add relationship indexes by relationship type(s) and property(or properties). So the capability is there, if needed, after you've ruled out refactoring of your model.

Answer (score 0):

I've voted for this question to be migrated to SO, and answering it while hoping it to be really migrated. I used Neo4j a couple of years. Although it has changed a lot since then, the principles of being a graph database won't alter much I believe. In my opinion, if you need a lot of indices to promptly query the relationships between the nodes, you could have designed your data model in some other way such that it focuses more on the graph nodes (just for example, relationships being your nodes, and nodes being your relationships as in *line graph*); because the querying mechanism (e.g. Cypher query) is generally optimised for the nodes.